# how to call a function after a function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my two function i want execute the GetAllSLUDetails() at first and then get broadcase value from the controllerTa. So could you help me

```
 //==============call the state function after changed Country Name // get broadcase value from the controllerTa=================    
        $scope.$on('evtTACountryCodeSelect', function (event, args) {
            $scope.message = args.message;

            var taCountryCode = $scope.message.split(",")[0];         

            var taStateCode = $scope.message.split(",")[1];

            alert(taCountryCode);
            alert(taStateCode);

            GetAllSLUDetails(taCountryCode);
            alert(taStateCode);

            if (taStateCode != "") {              
                document.getElementById("ddlState").value = taStateCode;
            }
        });

        //================To Get All Records ====================== 
        function GetAllSLUDetails(CountryCode) {
           // alert('ctrl State' + CountryCode);
            var Data = stateService.getSLU(CountryCode);
            Data.then(function (d) {
                $scope.StateListUpdate = d.data;
                //alert(d.data);
                alert(JSON.stringify(d));
            }, function () {
                alert('Error');
            });

        }
```

Comment: call next function as a `callback` function.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain better what you are trying to do, but generally you can achieve executing a function after another using callbacks or promises.

So if you want to execute something after the GetAllSLUDetails you can either:

```
$scope.$on('evtTACountryCodeSelect', function (event, args) {
    GetAllSLUDetails(taCountryCode, function() {  // THIS
        // Do whatever
    });
});

function GetAllSLUDetails(CountryCode, callback) {
    // alert('ctrl State' + CountryCode);
    var Data = stateService.getSLU(CountryCode);
    Data.then(function (d) {
        $scope.StateListUpdate = d.data;
        //alert(d.data);
        alert(JSON.stringify(d));
        callback(); // THIS
    }, function () {
        alert('Error');
    });
}
```

or using Promise:

```
$scope.$on('evtTACountryCodeSelect', function (event, args) {
    GetAllSLUDetails(taCountryCode).then(function() {  // THIS
        // Do whatever
    });
});

function GetAllSLUDetails(CountryCode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // THIS
        // alert('ctrl State' + CountryCode);
        var Data = stateService.getSLU(CountryCode);
        Data.then(function (d) {
            $scope.StateListUpdate = d.data;
            //alert(d.data);
            alert(JSON.stringify(d));
            resolve(d); // THIS
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Error');
            reject(error); // THIS
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Here 
alert('ctrl State' + CountryCode); on 

function GetAllSLUDetails(CountryCode) {

}

does not working@AlexD

Comment: Can you do a fiddle or a plunkr? Whats not working exactly?